# RxJS Subject gives me a (SystemJS) Unexpected token <(…)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I got this typescript code:

```
_live: Subject<Match[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Match[]>(null);
_pre: Subject<Match[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Match[]>(null);
```

But I keeps getting this Error:

> (SystemJS) Unexpected token <(…).

When those 2 variables are removed everything else works fine. Is there a fix for this or something else that replace Subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing Subject like this-

```
import { Subject }          from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

or import everything from RxJS like this-

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'; 
// adds ALL RxJS statics & operators to Observable
```

See if this helps.